# What is the GWT replacement for java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String arg)

Tags: java, regex, gwt

In my app I need the code like:

`string1.replaceAll(string2, myConstatntString)`

Problem is that `string1` and `string2` can contain special symbols like `'('`.

I wish to quote `string2` using  `java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(String arg)`:

`string1.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(string2), myConstatntString);`

But `java.util.regex.Pattern` is not available in GWT client side. Does GWT have any replacements for `Pattern.quote`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there isn't, because JavaScript doesn't have its own method. What you can do is to use `String.replace()` instead of `String.replaceAll()`, given that you don't need regexp at all. If you do, you will have to write your own method.

This is how it is done in JavaScript: [Is there a RegExp.escape function in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3561493/1667977)

And this is how it is done in Java:

```
public static String quote(String s) {
    int slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E");
    if (slashEIndex == -1)
        return "\\Q" + s + "\\E";

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length() * 2);
    sb.append("\\Q");
    slashEIndex = 0;
    int current = 0;
    while ((slashEIndex = s.indexOf("\\E", current)) != -1) {
        sb.append(s.substring(current, slashEIndex));
        current = slashEIndex + 2;
        sb.append("\\E\\\\E\\Q");
    }
    sb.append(s.substring(current, s.length()));
    sb.append("\\E");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

From: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/regex/Pattern.java

(the actual implementation in Java 1.5+)

Comment: +1 i don't think there's one either. You could write a native method in GWT the calls the JS method.